# How to convert varchar to datetime format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert `varchar` date value to `datetime` using this query

```
SELECT  
    CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, [Assigned_DT]), 105) + ' ' + 
    CONVERT(varchar(8), CONVERT(datetime, [Assigned_DT]), 14)
```

But for this date '16/02/2021 1:55 PM' I get this error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

How can I convert so it is valid - the format of the dates are mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: A quick look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will tell you why. Style `105` is `dd-mm-yyyy`, which you explicitly say is not the format of your value.

Comment: but 16/02/2021 can ONLY be DD/MM/YYYY. Something is wrong somewhere. If you have inconsistent formats in your strings, your goal of converting might be logically impossible.

Comment: The real lesson to learn is, `varchar` is not "one size fits all" data type. It is an awful data type for dates.

Answer (score 2):

The `105` number in the code is the wrong style number. It's for Italian `dd-mm-yyyy` values (note the `-` vs `/`). You need to read the [CONVERT() function docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and find the style number that matches your input. I could do that for you, but now that I've pointed you where to look, doing it yourself is good practice.

Comment: C'mon buddy, if you want rep for the answer, you really should put some effort into providing an actual answer, otherwise this is really just a comment. While your link to the external documentation is valid today, we should include excerpts from the linked resource to maintain the integrity of this site as a knowledge base. Hint, the answer is use `101` instead of `105`